# Dynamically accessing object property in .map array function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

i want to have reusable function that maps an array of objects based on property passed as parameter to function.

Here's my code:

```
let arr = [
  {
    country: 'poland',
    population: 380000
  },
  {
    country: 'bangladesh',
    population: 3492423
  }
]

function filterMyArr (myArr, condition) {
  return myArr.map(element => element.country)
}

console.log(filterMyArr(arr))
```

When i change code and try to pass condition, while executing it doesn't work. I want to call a function with second parameter for example filterMyArr(arr, country) and to have similar outcome. I want it to be reusable so i can use it for population or any other property. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Try this

```js
let arr = [
  {
    country: 'poland',
    population: 380000
  },
  {
    country: 'bangladesh',
    population: 3492423
  }
]

function filterMyArr (myArr, condition) {
  return myArr.map(element => element[condition])
}

console.log('Countries - ', filterMyArr(arr, 'country'))

console.log('Population - ', filterMyArr(arr, 'population'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**, like this:

```
function filterMyArr (myArr, condition) {
  return myArr.map(element => element[condition])
}
```

Where you pass the `condition` as a `string` as a name of a property in your `object`.

**Note:**

But just be aware that calling the function without this `condition` argument, will throw an error, when you do:

```
console.log(filterMyArr(arr))
```

Comment: You can set default value of `condition` to `country`

Comment: @Mohammad Yes we can, it's one way of doing things. It depends on the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass second argument (property) as a string and access it using bracket notation:

```js
let arr = [
  {country: 'poland', population: 380000},
  {country: 'bangladesh', population: 3492423}
];

function filterMyArr (myArr, prop) {
  return myArr.map(obj => obj[prop]);
}

console.log(filterMyArr(arr, 'country'));
console.log(filterMyArr(arr, 'population'));
```

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to try brackets, my bad : /